# Matrix Subset Operations in Array

Tags: c

I have a matrix multiplication problem. We have an image matrix which can be have variable size. It is required to calculate C = A*B for every possible nxn. C will be added to output image as seen in figure. The center point of A Matrix is located in the lower triangle. Also, B is placed diagonally symmetric to A. A can be overlap, so, B can be overlap too. Figures can be seen in below for more detailed understand:

Blue X points represent all possible mid points of A. Algorithm should just do multiply A and diagonally mirrored version of A or called B. I done it with lots of for loop. I need to reduce number of for that I used. Could you help me please?

What kind of algorithm can be used for this problem? I have some confusing points.

Could you please help me with your genius algorithm talents? Or could you direct me to an expert?

**Original Questions is below:**

Thanks.

Update:

```
#define SIZE_ARRAY 20
#define SIZE_WINDOW 5
#define WINDOW_OFFSET 2
#define INDEX_OFFSET 1
#define START_OFFSET_COLUMN 2
#define START_OFFSET_ROW 3
#define END_OFFSET_COLUMN 3
#define END_OFFSET_ROW 2
#define GET_LOWER_DIAGONAL_INDEX_MIN_ROW (START_OFFSET_ROW);
#define GET_LOWER_DIAGONAL_INDEX_MAX_ROW (SIZE_ARRAY - INDEX_OFFSET - END_OFFSET_ROW)
#define GET_LOWER_DIAGONAL_INDEX_MIN_COL (START_OFFSET_COLUMN);
#define GET_LOWER_DIAGONAL_INDEX_MAX_COL (SIZE_ARRAY - INDEX_OFFSET - END_OFFSET_COLUMN)
uint32_t lowerDiagonalIndexMinRow = GET_LOWER_DIAGONAL_INDEX_MIN_ROW;
uint32_t lowerDiagonalIndexMaxRow = GET_LOWER_DIAGONAL_INDEX_MAX_ROW;
uint32_t lowerDiagonalIndexMinCol = GET_LOWER_DIAGONAL_INDEX_MIN_COL;
uint32_t lowerDiagonalIndexMaxCol = GET_LOWER_DIAGONAL_INDEX_MAX_COL;
void parallelMultiplication_Stable_Master()
{
    startTimeStamp = omp_get_wtime();

    #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(8) private(outerIterRow, outerIterCol,rA,cA,rB,cB) shared(inputImage, outputImage)
    for(outerIterRow = lowerDiagonalIndexMinRow; outerIterRow < lowerDiagonalIndexMaxRow; outerIterRow++)
    {
        for(outerIterCol = lowerDiagonalIndexMinCol; outerIterCol < lowerDiagonalIndexMaxCol; outerIterCol++)
        {
            if(outerIterCol + 1 < outerIterRow)
            {
                rA = outerIterRow - WINDOW_OFFSET;
                cA = outerIterCol - WINDOW_OFFSET;

                rB = outerIterCol - WINDOW_OFFSET;
                cB = outerIterRow - WINDOW_OFFSET;

                for(i= outerIterRow - WINDOW_OFFSET; i <= outerIterRow + WINDOW_OFFSET; i++)
                {
                    for(j= outerIterCol - WINDOW_OFFSET; j <= outerIterCol + WINDOW_OFFSET; j++)
                    {
                        for(k=0; k < SIZE_WINDOW; k++)
                        {
                            #pragma omp critical
                            outputImage[i][j] += inputImage[rA][cA+k] * inputImage[rB+k][cB];
                        }
                        cB++;
                        rA++;
                    }
                    rB++;
                    cA++;
                    printf("Thread Number - %d",omp_get_thread_num());
                }
            }
        }
    }
    stopTimeStamp = omp_get_wtime();
    printArray(outputImage,"Output Image");
    printConsoleNotification(100, startTimeStamp, stopTimeStamp);
}
```

I am getting segmentation fault error if I set up thread count more than "1". What is the trick ?

Comment: A few questions: 1. The different C areas in the output image overlap. Do you accumulate the results? 2. What do you mean with "Or will A be stay safe through in the lower triangle?" 3. Do you simply want to loop through all valid positions for A and compute the result?

Comment: Also, how does this relate to OpenMP? It's in your tags but not your question. Do you want to parallelize?

Comment: You said 'The center point of A Matrix is located in the lower triangle' then ask 'Will the A Matrix move through upper triangle border?'. You tell us, it's your question. Also, from you images, C has the same position as A so do you really only want the C sums from the lower left half? This question is not well defined.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you need two loops for the center point of A, and then three (short) loops for the matrix-matrix multplication of A and B. That makes 5 and I don't think you can do it more compactly, other than unrolling some of the length-5 loops.

Comment: Dear @Homer512, 1-) Yes, I want to accumulate. 2-) I mean that the center of A matrix can only be in the lower triangle denoted by the green color in the figure below. 3-) Yes, I want to simply loop through all valid positions for the green area and compute A*B matrix results. I tried it but too many loops are required and I am getting a segmentation core dump errors in my OpenMP algorithm. So, I want to create a robust serial algorithm to make it parallel.

Comment: Dear @SimonGoater, thank you for inducing me. This is the second time creating this question. I didn't understand some portions well too. I am fixing that and sharing the original one.

Comment: Dear @VictorEijkhout, yes I did it with 5 loops logically. But in the practice, it requires more. Because in C++ I couldn't handle getting each 5x5 A and B matrixes dynamically. So, for each A and B matrix I am usign 3 more loops.

Comment: In C++ use `.data()` to get the array. Then `for (i...) for (j...) c[i+j*n] = ....` There is aabsolutely no need for more loops.

Comment: Hi Dear @VictorEijkhout, I didn't understand details but I done it by different way. I can also listen your details. However, I have another issue. I am getting segmentation fault error. I updated question with my codes. Could you please help me?

Comment: I am getting a segmentation fault error if I set up thread count of more than "1". What is the trick?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not providing a solution, but some thoughts that may help the OP exploring a possible approach.

You can evaluate each element of the resulting C matrix directly, from the values of the original matrix in a way similar to a [convolution operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution).

Consider the following image (sorry if it's confusing):

[image]
[image]

Instead of computing each matrix product for every A submatrix, you can evaluate the value of each C<sub>i, j</sub> from the values in the shaded areas.

Note that C<sub>i, j</sub> depends only on a small subset of row i and that the elements of the upper right triangular submatrix (where the B submatrices are picked) could be copied and maybe transposed in a more chache-friendly accomodation.

Alternatively, it may be worth exploring an approach where for every possible B<sub>i, j</sub>, all the corresponding elements of C are evaluated.

**Edit**

Note that you can actually save a lot of calculations (and maybe cache misses) by grouping the terms, see e.g. the first two elements of row i in A:

[image]
[image]

More formally

C<sub>i,j</sub> =  A<sub>i,j-4</sub> · (B<sub>j-4,i</sub> + B<sub>j-4,i+1</sub> + B<sub>j-4,i+2</sub> + B<sub>j-4,i+3</sub> + B<sub>j-4,i+4</sub>)
C<sub>i,j</sub> += A<sub>i,j-3</sub> · (B<sub>j-3,i-1</sub> + B<sub>j-3,i+4</sub> + 2·(B<sub>j-3,i</sub> + B<sub>j-3,i+1</sub> + B<sub>j-3,i+2</sub> + B<sub>j-3,i+3</sub>))
C<sub>i,j</sub> += A<sub>i,j-2</sub> · (B<sub>j-2,i-2</sub> + B<sub>j-2,i+4</sub> + 2·(B<sub>j-2,i-1</sub> + B<sub>j-2,i+3</sub>) + 3·(B<sub>j-2,i</sub> + B<sub>j-2,i+1</sub> + B<sub>j-2,i+2</sub>))
C<sub>i,j</sub> += A<sub>i,j-1</sub> · (B<sub>j-1,i-3</sub> + B<sub>j-1,i+4</sub> + 2·(B<sub>j-1,i-2</sub> + B<sub>j-1,i+3</sub>) + 3·(B<sub>j-1,i-1</sub> + B<sub>j-1,i+2</sub>) + 4·(B<sub>j-1,i</sub> + B<sub>j-1,i+1</sub>))
C<sub>i,j</sub> += A<sub>i,j</sub> · (B<sub>j,i-4</sub> + B<sub>j,i+4</sub> + 2·(B<sub>j,i-3</sub> + B<sub>j,i+3</sub>) + 3·(B<sub>j,i-2</sub> + B<sub>j,i+2</sub>) + 4·(B<sub>j,i-1</sub> + B<sub>j,i+1</sub>) + 5·B<sub>j,i</sub>)
C<sub>i,j</sub> += A<sub>i,j+1</sub> · (B<sub>j+1,i-4</sub> + B<sub>j+1,i+3</sub> + 2·(B<sub>j+1,i-3</sub> + B<sub>j+1,i+2</sub>) + 3·(B<sub>j+1,i-2</sub> + B<sub>j+1,i+1</sub>) + 4·(B<sub>j+1,i-1</sub> + B<sub>j+1,i</sub>))
C<sub>i,j</sub> += A<sub>i,j+2</sub> · (B<sub>j+2,i-4</sub> + B<sub>j+2,i+2</sub> + 2·(B<sub>j+2,i-3</sub> + B<sub>j+2,i+1</sub>) + 3·(B<sub>j+2,i-2</sub> + B<sub>j+2,i-1</sub> + B<sub>j+2,i</sub>))
C<sub>i,j</sub> += A<sub>i,j+3</sub> · (B<sub>j+3,i-4</sub> + B<sub>j+3,i+1</sub> + 2·(B<sub>j+3,i-3</sub> + B<sub>j+3,i-2</sub> + B<sub>j+3,i-1</sub> + B<sub>j+3,i</sub>))
C<sub>i,j</sub> += A<sub>i,j+4</sub> · (B<sub>j+4,i-4</sub> + B<sub>j+4,i-3</sub> + B<sub>j+4,i-2</sub> + B<sub>j+4,i-1</sub> + B<sub>j+4,i</sub>)

If I correctly estimated, this requires something like 60 additions and 25 (possibly fused) multiplications, compared to 125 operations like C<sub>i,j</sub> += A<sub>i,k</sub> · B<sub>k,i</sub> spread all over the places.

I think that cache-locality may have a bigger impact on performance than the mere reduction of operations.

We could also precompute all the values

S<sub>i,j</sub> = B<sub>j,i</sub> + B<sub>j,i+1</sub> + B<sub>j,i+2</sub> + B<sub>j,i+3</sub> + B<sub>j,i+4</sub>

Then the previous formulas become

C<sub>i,j</sub> =  A<sub>i,j-4</sub> · S<sub>j-4,i</sub>
C<sub>i,j</sub> += A<sub>i,j-3</sub> · (S<sub>j-3,i-1</sub> + S<sub>j-3,i</sub>)
C<sub>i,j</sub> += A<sub>i,j-2</sub> · (S<sub>j-2,i-2</sub> + S<sub>j-2,i-1</sub> + S<sub>j-2,i</sub>)
C<sub>i,j</sub> += A<sub>i,j-1</sub> · (S<sub>j-1,i-3</sub> + S<sub>j-1,i-2</sub> + S<sub>j-1,i-1</sub> + S<sub>j-1,i</sub>)
C<sub>i,j</sub> += A<sub>i,j</sub> · (S<sub>j,i-4</sub> + S<sub>j,i-3</sub> + S<sub>j,i-2</sub> + S<sub>j,i-1</sub> + S<sub>j,i</sub>)
C<sub>i,j</sub> += A<sub>i,j+1</sub> · (S<sub>j+1,i-4</sub> + S<sub>j+1,i-3</sub> + S<sub>j+1,i-2</sub> + S<sub>j+1,i-1</sub>)
C<sub>i,j</sub> += A<sub>i,j+2</sub> · (S<sub>j+2,i-4</sub> + S<sub>j+2,i-3</sub> + S<sub>j+2,i-2</sub>)
C<sub>i,j</sub> += A<sub>i,j+3</sub> · (S<sub>j+3,i-4</sub> + S<sub>j+3,i-3</sub>)
C<sub>i,j</sub> += A<sub>i,j+4</sub> · S<sub>j+4,i-4</sub>

Comment: Hi Dear @Bob__ thank you for your help. How did you get this simulation outputs? Could you share with us?

Comment: @KursatCAKAL Well, in the dumb way ;) I just drew all the frames with a graphic software (it was Affinity Designer, actually), exported as png files and merged the last ones into animated png (there are online services). Sorry if I haven't wrote any formula, but I have to first visualize a problem in order to understand it.

Comment: Nice shot :)) Dear @Bob__, it helps me a lot. Thank you for your help. I am still running on the issue. I hope it goes well. I am new to the issue and time is drastically running out.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my take. I wrote this before OP showed any code, so I'm not following any of their code patterns.

I start with a suitable image struct, just for my own sanity.

```c
struct Image
{
    float* values;
    int rows, cols;
};

struct Image image_allocate(int rows, int cols)
{
    struct Image rtrn;
    rtrn.rows = rows;
    rtrn.cols = cols;
    rtrn.values = malloc(sizeof(float) * rows * cols);
    return rtrn;
}
void image_fill(struct Image* img)
{
    ptrdiff_t row, col;
    for(row = 0; row < img->rows; ++row)
        for(col = 0; col < img->cols; ++col)
            img->values[row * img->cols + col] = rand() * (1.f / RAND_MAX);
}
void image_print(const struct Image* img)
{
    ptrdiff_t row, col;
    for(row = 0; row < img->rows; ++row) {
        for(col = 0; col < img->cols; ++col)
            printf("%.3f ", img->values[row * img->cols + col]);
        putchar('\n');
    }
    putchar('\n');
}
```

A 5x5 matrix multiplication is too small to reasonably dispatch to BLAS. So I write a simple version myself that can be loop-unrolled and / or inlined. This routine could use a couple of micro-optimizations but let's keep it simple for now.

```c
/** out += left * right for 5x5 sub-matrices */
static void mat_mul_5x5(
    float* restrict out, const float* left, const float* right, int cols)
{
    ptrdiff_t row, col, inner;
    float sum;
    for(row = 0; row < 5; ++row) {
        for(col = 0; col < 5; ++col) {
            sum = out[row * cols + col];
            for(inner = 0; inner < 5; ++inner)
                sum += left[row * cols + inner] * right[inner * cols + col];
            out[row * cols + col] = sum;
        }
    }
}
```

Now for the single-threaded implementation of the main algorithm. Again, nothing fancy. We just iterate over the lower triangular matrix, excluding the diagonal. I keep track of the top-left corner instead of the center point. Makes index computation a bit simpler.

```c
void compute_ltr(struct Image* restrict out, const struct Image* in)
{
    ptrdiff_t top, left, end;
    /* if image is not quadratic, find quadratic subset */
    end = out->rows < out->cols ? out->rows : out->cols;
    assert(in->rows == out->rows && in->cols == out->cols);
    memset(out->values, 0, sizeof(float) * out->rows * out->cols);
    for(top = 1; top <= end - 5; ++top)
        for(left = 0; left < top; ++left)
            mat_mul_5x5(out->values + top * out->cols + left,
                        in->values + top * in->cols + left,
                        in->values + left * in->cols + top,
                        in->cols);
}
```

The parallelization is a bit tricky because we have to make sure the threads don't overlap in their output matrices. A critical section, atomics or similar stuff would cost too much performance.

A simpler solution is a strided approach: If we always keep the threads 5 rows apart, they cannot interfere. So we simply compute every fifth row, synchronize all threads, then compute the next set of rows, five apart, and so on.

```c
void compute_ltr_parallel(struct Image* restrict out, const struct Image* in)
{
    /* if image is not quadratic, find quadratic subset */
    const ptrdiff_t end = out->rows < out->cols ? out->rows : out->cols;
    assert(in->rows == out->rows && in->cols == out->cols);
    memset(out->values, 0, sizeof(float) * out->rows * out->cols);
    /*
     * Keep the parallel section open for multiple loops to reduce
     * overhead
     */
#   pragma omp parallel
    {
        ptrdiff_t top, left, offset;
        for(offset = 0; offset < 5; ++offset) {
            /* Use dynamic scheduling because the work per row varies */
#           pragma omp for schedule(dynamic)
            for(top = 1 + offset; top <= end - 5; top += 5)
                for(left = 0; left < top; ++left)
                    mat_mul_5x5(out->values + top * out->cols + left,
                                in->values + top * in->cols + left,
                                in->values + left * in->cols + top,
                                in->cols);
        }
    }
}
```

My benchmark with 1000 iterations of a 1000x1000 image show 7 seconds for the serial version and 1.2 seconds for the parallelized version on my 8 core / 16 thread CPU.

**EDIT for completeness:** Here are the includes and the main for benchmarking.

```c
#include <assert.h>
#include <stddef.h>
/* using ptrdiff_t */
#include <stdlib.h>
/* using malloc */
#include <stdio.h>
/* using printf */
#include <string.h>
/* using memset */

/* Insert code from above here */

int main()
{
    int rows = 1000, cols = 1000, rep = 1000;
    struct Image in, out;
    in = image_allocate(rows, cols);
    out = image_allocate(rows, cols);
    image_fill(&in);
# if 1
    do
        compute_ltr_parallel(&out, &in);
    while(--rep);
# else
    do
        compute_ltr(&out, &in);
    while(--rep);
# endif
}
```

Compile with `gcc -O3 -fopenmp`.

Regarding the comment, and also your way of using OpenMP: Don't overcomplicate things with unnecessary directives. OpenMP can figure out how many threads are available itself. And private variables can easily be declared within the parallel section (usually).

If you want a specific number of threads, just call with the appropriate environment variable, e.g. on Linux call `OMP_NUM_THREADS=8 ./executable`

Comment: Hi Dear @Homer512, did you try this code by setting any number of thread counts? Could you please link me your test codes ? It is not working for me. I think I have a problem with my GCC version or OMP version or any includes :(

Comment: @KursatCAKAL No, I've not investigated the scaling for different thread counts. I've posted the remaining code

Comment: Hi Dear @Home512, I tried using "pragma omp for num_threads(8) schedule(dynamic)" but it is reverting error. What should I do for testing code with different number of thread count?

Comment: By the way, I appreciate your help. God brought us together :)

Comment: Dear @Homer512, Target has been taken down !! You are amazing :)). Do you have a real name? LinkedIn, Github or etc. I want to follow you if you let me.